# Let $k$ be a field then $kG$ k-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In my course of commutative algebra, the professor told us the follow:

Let $k$ be a field and let $G$ be a group. then $kG$ is a $k$-algebra.

I don't understand this  totally. I know that a $k$-algebra is a ring with structure of module, in this sense, what is the action for $kG$?

Is $k \times kG \to kG$? or
is $k \times G \to G$ ?

My question arise because i don't understand the structure of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. I need to know very good this structure because I want to show that $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$

Comment: Why don't you start by writing down your definition of $k[G]$?

Comment: With $G=\Bbb{Z/nZ}$ then $k[G]\cong k[x]/(x^n-1)$, the isomorphism is to send $1\in G$ to $x$. In $k[G]$, for an arbitrary group $G$, the elements of $k$ commute with the $g$'s

Answer (score 1):

A module over a field is just a vector space. Here, the scalar multiplication is simply $\lambda (\sum_{g\in G} a_gg)=\sum_{g\in G} (\lambda a_g)g$.